# Как добавить onclick в тэг div?

Tags: javascript

Динамически создаю тэг div (в моём случае нужно только динамически).

```
    var OnlineChat=new Object();
    OnlineChat.divchat=document.createElement('div');
    OnlineChat.divchat.id = "OnlineChat";
    OnlineChat.divchat.className = 'OnlineChat';
    OnlineChat.divchat.onclick='showFrame()';
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(OnlineChat.divchat);
```

У меня создаёться <div id="OnlineChat" class="OnlineChat"></div>.  Но почему-то нету onclick? Как добавить onclick в div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо так:

```
...    
OnlineChat.divchat.onclick=showFrame;
...
```

Вот пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div> 
<style>
#OnlineChat{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #00FF00;
}
</style>
<script>
function showFrame(){
    alert("OK!");
}
var OnlineChat=new Object();
    OnlineChat.divchat=document.createElement('div');
    OnlineChat.divchat.id = "OnlineChat";
    OnlineChat.divchat.className = 'OnlineChat';
    OnlineChat.divchat.onclick=showFrame;
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(OnlineChat.divchat);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Нет, почему-то и так не работает. в div даже onclick не вставляет, не говоря уже о вызове функции showFrame

Comment: У меня во всех браузерах 100% работает! Низнаю что у вас не так приведите полный код!

Comment: Chrome. Всё, похоже я понял в чём дело было. Спасибо Вам большое.

Comment: Не за что :)

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression - вот тут подробнее

Пример с вводом параметров 
**`OnlineChat.divchat.onclick=function(){ showFrame(параметры); };`**